# DIV não respeita dimensão após mouse-over

Tags: css, css3

estou com esse **código**.

A ideia é fazer com que a `div.topo` **acompanhasse** a **largura** do **browse** em até 90%  **limitado** á **1440px** quando ele para de acompanhar e mantem a largura fixa.

Essa parte está OK.

O problema é que quando eu passo o **mouse** sobre a `div`, isto é, acontece o **mouse-over**, então o limite de **1440px** se perde e a **div** aumenta

```css
  @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after,
  *:active,
  *:hover {
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   outline: none;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
   height: 100%;
   font-family: "Futura Std Book";
  }
  
  a {
   text-decoration: none;
   /*color: #fff*/
  }
  
  ul {
   list-style: none;
  }
  
  label {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  label img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  img {
   height: auto;
  }
  
  body> div {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   max-width: 1440px;
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  body> div> div {
   flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  body div.topo {
   justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  body div.topo ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   padding: 0 2px;
   border: .1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
 <div class=topo>
  <div class=logo><img src="img/home.jpg" style="width: 300px;"/>
  </div>

  <div class=menu>

   <ul>
    <li>Institucional</li><!--
   --><li>Missão</li><!--
   --><li>Visão</li><!--
   --><li>Valores</li><!--
   --><li>Relacionamento</li><!--
   --><li>Cartão Fidelidade</li><!--
   --><li>Economia.</li><!--
   --><li>Contato</li><!--
   --><li>Dúvidas</li>

   </ul>


  </div>
 </div>
```

Ciei um **recurso**, até funcionou, mas achei meio gabiarra.

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando.

O recurso é:

```
body > div,
body > div:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1440px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove o `*:hover` do seu css, isso faz com que todos os elementos da página sofram alterações no `hover`, no caso da `div` é que deixa a margem como 0 em todas as direções, deixando de ficar centralizada de quando estava com a regra `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: Então, se você estiver se referindo ao primeiro bloco do CSS onde está a chamada à fonte externa, este bloco que contem os pseudo eventos foi necessário pois se não tiver ele, o estilo não se aplica aos pseudo eventos Mas se você estiver se referindo à adaptação body > div:hover {}, se eu remover o hover, então o erri acontece!

Comment: Você só remove o `*:hover` mesmo do seu css